# Trouble mounting ActiveDirectory Drive in PowerShell using .Net Core

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, powershell-core

We're creating a micro-service to do a few things in AD. This service requires that active directory be mounted to `AD` as a PSDrive.

I understand how the mounting works and can do it successfully in PowerShell on the server.

For the module to be added we had to specify the physical location to `ActiveDirectory.psd1` for it to import.

I suspect this is the reason why the following script does not execute successfully.

Script:
`New-PSDrive -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Name AD -Root \"\" -Server (Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service PrimaryDC).Name`

If executed like this, the exception thrown says that the parameter `Server` is invalid.

When removing this parameter, the exception says that the provider `ActiveDirectory` does not exist.

Am I taking the right approach to this?

Here is the C# code:

```
string moduleDirectory = Configuration["AppSettings:Directories:PowerShellModules"];

var requiredPowerShellModules = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "ActiveDirectory", $"{moduleDirectory}\\ActiveDirectory\\ActiveDirectory.psd1" }
};

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> module in requiredPowerShellModules)
{
    bool hasModule = Modules.HasModule(module.Key, powerShell);

    if (!hasModule)
    {
        Modules.ImportModule(module.Value, powerShell);

        if (!Modules.HasModule(module.Key, powerShell))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Unable to import PowerShell module: \"{module.Key}\" at path \"{module.Value}\"");
        }
    }
}

//Check if AD Drive mounted
var adDriveResult = powerShell.AddScript("Get-PSDrive AD -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue").Invoke();

//Mount AD Drive if not exists
if (adDriveResult.Count != 1)
    powerShell
        .AddScript("New-PSDrive -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Name AD -Root \"\" -Server (Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service PrimaryDC).Name ") //
            .Invoke();
```

Comment: What does `Get-PSProvider ActiveDirectory` yield?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I'll update the app to test and update the post

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen

`The term 'Get-PSProvider ActiveDirectory' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`

Interesting. Not sure why this would be an issue.

Comment: I might have made a mistake. Will update in a few minutes

Comment: `Get-PSProvider ActiveDirectory` returned a single result with AD. I've made a few changes.

Seems like I've sorted out the issue by using a Remote runspace. Which solves my problem, but does not solve the question unfortunately.

Comment: If you figured out how to solve it (either by using a separate runspace or whatever), then that is the answer :) Feel free to post a self-answer with the approach you ended up taking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by an outdated version of ActiveDirectory powershell module.

Version `1.0.0.0` was on the server, instead of `1.0.1.0`.